# Can I parameterize the type name of a log4net Appender in the app.config?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, logging, log4net

I am using log4net within a Console Application. My configuration file allow me to get the filename from Input:

Config file:

```
<appender name="CustomRollingFileAppender" type="MyApp.UTIL.CustomRollingFileAppender">
      <threshold value="ALL"/>
      <param name="file" value=""/>
      <param name="appendToFile" value="false"/>
      <param name="maximumFileSize" value="20000KB"/>
      <param name="maxSizeRollBackups" value="200"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%-5.5level] %logger - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
</appender>
```

Override File Parameter:

```
namespace ConsoleApplicationTemplate.UTIL
{
    public class CustomRollingFileAppender : log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender
    {
        public override string File
        {
            get { return base.File; }
            set
            {
                //Filename string taken as Input
                base.File = Program.options.LogFile; 
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

This is working like a charm, but I need to change the parameter **type** inside the tag **appender**. I have searched around and find out that I can use properties within configuration file. So I have modified my config file as following:

```
<appender name="CustomRollingFileAppender" type="%property{ApplicationName}.UTIL.CustomRollingFileAppender">
      <threshold value="ALL"/>
      <param name="file" value=""/>
      <param name="appendToFile" value="false"/>
      <param name="maximumFileSize" value="20000KB"/>
      <param name="maxSizeRollBackups" value="200"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%-5.5level] %logger - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
</appender>
```

And I also need to change the property value as following:

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["ApplicationName"] = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
private static log4net.ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

When log4net read the configuration file I get the following error (which doesn't raise an exception):

```
log4net:ERROR Could not create Appender [CustomRollingFileAppender] of type [%property{ApplicationName}.UTIL.CustomRollingFileAppender]. Reported error follows.
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type [%property{ApplicationName}.UTIL.CustomRollingFileAppender]. Tried assembly [log4net, Version=1.2.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a] and all loaded assemblies 
    at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(Assembly relativeAssembly, String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
    at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) 
    at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ParseAppender(XmlEle
    ment appenderElement)
```

Comment: I don't think the type attribute allows parameters. But I can't think of a reason why you would ever want to parameterize this. Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to parametrize this because i want to make a Console Application  Template with log4net embedded.

Comment: As an alternative to log4net parameterization, could you use the Visual Studio template system to put the relevant name in the config file?

Comment: That's also a way to do it. I have to dig into VS2010 template a little more than, cause at the moment i have noe xperience with template variable.

Comment: @Clafou, it seems your two comments are an answer. You should post this recommendation. I agree that it's not possible.

Comment: @AnthonyMastrean, thanks for your input! I did just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it appears that the answer is no: Unlike some of the other log4net config  elements, the appender element's type attribute does not support parameters.

As discussed in the comments to your question, since what you are trying to achieve is making a Visual Studio project template that provides its own log4net appender type, a solution would be to make use of the Visual Studio templating system to write the relevant attribute value in the .config file.